# jQuery - animation toggle height by click on button

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to show more text by clicking on a button.
how can I animate this? I add a new class by click on the button. I want it to have a scroll down effect by add the new class. It doesn't work. Do I have to add the class to another div? or is the css wrong? Thanks for help..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const hiddenElement = $('.paragraph-small');
  $('.show-more').click(function(){
    hiddenElement.toggleClass('paragraph-large');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.paragraph-small {
  max-width: 500px;
  text-align: justify !important;
  margin: 1rem auto 3rem;
}

.hidden-text {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.paragraph-large .hidden-text {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: visible;
  transition: all linear 2.5s;;
}


.show-more {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-box">
  <div class="paragraph-small">
    <div class="visible-text">
      <span>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore                     magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
      </span>
    </div>
                
    <div class="hidden-text">
      <span>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore e dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
      </span>
    </div>
  
    <div class="show-more"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot animate or transition to length values set to `auto`. Use the following approach instead: Do not define `height`, but instead `max-height`. Set this to zero for the hidden state, and to an absurdly high value like `10000px` for the visible state. That will make it work :)

Comment: @connexo ok thank you! :)  max-height works - but only for the button not for the text ;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it not going to work with `height: auto`
You may want to change it to `max-height: 0` and `max-height: 1000px` (or whatever number you think that it should not create a scrollbar); but to be honest, this will not work smooth as you want (because the `max-height`, it will be delay between when you press the square and when it actually scoll up or down)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const hiddenElement = $('.paragraph-small');
  $('.show-more').click(function(){
    hiddenElement.toggleClass('paragraph-large');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.paragraph-small {
  max-width: 500px;
  text-align: justify !important;
  margin: 1rem auto 3rem;
}

.hidden-text {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all linear 2.5s;
}

.paragraph-large .hidden-text {
  max-height: 200px;
}


.show-more {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-box">
  <div class="paragraph-small">
    <div class="visible-text">
      <span>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore                     magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
      </span>
    </div>
                
    <div class="hidden-text">
      <span>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore e dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
      </span>
    </div>
  
    <div class="show-more"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok thank you :) i already updated my snippet. But now only the button scrolls down..

Comment: @azrm Ok, edited my answer; so i have remove the `overflow: visible` and move the `transition` from `paragraph-large .hidden-text` to `.hidden-text`. It work more smooth now!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/azesf25y/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.show-more').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('div.hidden-text').slideToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
.paragraph-small {
  max-width: 500px;
  text-align: justify !important;
  margin: 1rem auto 3rem;
}

.hidden-text {
  overflow: hidden;
  display:none;
}

.paragraph-large .hidden-text {
  max-height: 200px;
}


.show-more {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-box">
  <div class="paragraph-small">
    <div class="visible-text">
      <span>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
      </span>
    </div>
                
    <div class="hidden-text">
      <span>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore e dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
      </span>
    </div>
  
    <div class="show-more"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Changed code in `CSS`

```
.hidden-text {
  overflow: hidden;
  display:none;
}
```

No need to have transition in `CSS`, `jQuery slideToggle` will take care of it.

Changed code in `JavaScript`
On click `.show-more` will look for siblings with `div.hidden-text` and will slowly slideToggle.

**Reference Document:** http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

Hope this will help you.